# Angular toggle only selected item

Tags: angular, angular11

I have a list that's created dynamically.
Each item in the list will toggle when clicked.

Here is the .html code:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items">
    <li (click)="toggle($event)">{{text}}</li>
</ul>
```

And the .ts code:

```
toggle(event) {
    this.visible = !this.visible;
}
```

At the moment when I click on an item all the items in the list will toggle.

How can I change it so that only the clicked item will toggle?

Comment: It would be easier to have a look at the problem if you provided a
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
You can set one up over at [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com).

Comment: `this.visible` does nothing in the code you've shown, therefore it's a little hard to see what your intention is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not "toggle" situation, because how can you click something once it's invisible?

Anyway, you can make every `<li>` as component and than every `visible` will be in a different scope.
Another way, you can add to `item` object a property, for example `visible` and then every click will change the value as you want.

For example:

```html
<ul *ngFor="let item of items">
    <li *ngIf="item.visible" (click)="item.visible = false">{{item.text}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// make a global variable array
expandedItemIndexes = [] as any;
// Pass in an id you get from the html object
toggleItem(itemId): void {
  // Create a new variable that is an array
  
  if (this.expandedItemIndexes.includes(itemId)) {
    // if the index is included in the array of indexes, remove it
    this.expandedItemIndexes.splice(this.expandedItemIndexes.indexOf(itemId), 1);
  } else {
    // else push it into the array to expand the item
    this.expandedItemIndexes.push(itemId);
  }
}
```

In the HTML put `ngIf="expandedItemIndexes.includes(item.id)"` on the div you want to toggle.